# Encrypt AES key?

Tags: encryption, aes

Consider this scenario:

```
Key1 = random key
Key2 = random key
CombinedKey = Key1.encrypt (Key2)

Input = "test"
Step1 = CombinedKey.encrypt (Input)
Step2 = key2.decrypt (step1)
Result = key1.decrypt (step2)
```

Is Result == "test" if the encryption type is AES? Or for any other encryption algorythm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  AES is not a group.  For simplicity's sake, let's just say it this way:  AES encryption is not commutative.  Said another way, since AES is not a group, there is no key X such that encrypting with key Y and then key Z, key X can decrypt in one step.  There are no shortcuts.

If you encrypt `Input` with `CombinedKey` then only `CombinedKey` will decrypt it.  Using `key2` to decrypt `Step1` will result in only junk, not an intermediate result.

Comment: That's sad, but your answer is perfect.

Comment: :)  It's actually a good thing though it may be inconvenient in your use case. :)